# Issue with interacting with iPad accessory via Binding - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Barcode scanner accessory to which the iPad docks on to, hence i need to interface with the accessory to scan for barcode and use it in my application. To accomplish this, i followed the steps as enlisted here

[Xamarin Hep - Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/)

So I went on to create a "Binding" project, added the native library i.e. ".a" file , created the APIDefinition and Structs using Sharpie and finally added the Binding project reference to my application.

In the next step, when I tried to deploy the app to iPad, encountered the error with regards to Native Linking.

In order to fix this, i mentioned the "Framework" in the LinkWith file like:

**[assembly: LinkWith ("libBarCodeScannerSDK.a", SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = false, Frameworks="ExternalAccessory")]**

Having done all the things stated above, I was able to deploy the app.But I am unable to make my application work with the Barcode scanner accessory. When I check the status of the scanner, its always returned as "NotConnected".

I am clueless as to how to go about debugging this issue and getting it resolved. Do appreciate, if someone can give me pointers on this.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Why do you have ForceLoad = false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most (if not all) of external accessories must set `UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols` key inside the `info.plist` file, see the `info.plist` file that the native Xcode example that came with your scanner SDK has and copy the `UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols` section to your Xamarin's app `info.plist` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Exactly, I was able to figure it out after comparing my Xamarin app with the iOS sample which came with the scanner SDK.
Just needed to add "Supported external accessory protocols" property and its respective value in info.plist and voila.. started working.. Thanks delexsoto for the help though.